# Do open source web indexes exist?

Tags: web-crawler

Is there a open source web index that is based on spiders that progressively search and index more and more pages from the entire internet (not just 1 site)?  If such an index exists, what would I need in order to access it?  Are there API calls for this?

Comment: Like a search engine?

Comment: A search engine uses a web index.  The web index would be a data structure or structures possibly saved in a file(s).  The web index contains information as to what is stored on a web page.  My question is how can I access this data structure(s) from a computer program?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Gigablast](https://gigablast.com/) is an open-source web search engine.  The API is documented [here](https://gigablast.com/api.html).  I believe [this](https://github.com/gigablast/open-source-search-engine) is the source code, so you can run your own instance.

Comment: The first 2 of those 3 links don't seem to be up any more.